# Button that checks before going to a URL

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have a button that's value is set from an RPG program, when the button has a value I want for it to when clicked go to a url and when it doesn't have a value, either not display or just do nothing?

```
  <td>
      <div align="right">
           <input type="submit" id="ProdNo" name="Submit" value="<%= (KEC1KM) %>" onclick="goToProdSpec()" style="width:100%" />
      </div>
  </td>
```

My first attempt was to try the do nothing, but if its easier to hide it when it has no values I'd be interested.

Heres my attempt at the javascript side of this functionality, without the check it works fine, but when I incorporate the if it doesn't work at all

```
    function goToProdSpec(){
        var ButtonValue = document.getElementById('ProdNo').value;

        If(ButtonValue != ""){
        url = 'http://svr:7018/Enquiries/CMENPROC.rpgle?ProductCode=' + ButtonValue;    
        window.location.href = url;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages in the browser's debug console? Try adding `console.log(ButtonValue)` to your function to check what the value is.

Comment: Is that a capital 'I' in the ``if``? (And does it matter? On mobile - can't check.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the value to function from html something like this

```
<td><div align="right"><input type="submit" id="ProdNo" name="Submit" value="<%= (KEC1KM) %>" onclick="goToProdSpec(this.value)" style="width:100%" /></div></td>
```

And in javascript use like this

```
function goToProdSpec(value)
{
   If(value != "")
   {
        url = 'http://svr:7018/Enquiries/CMENPROC.rpgle?ProductCode=' + value;    
        window.location.href = url;
   }
}
```

Try this might be it will work

Answer (score 0):

> My first attempt was to try the do nothing, but if its easier to hide it when it has no values I'd be interested.

Hiding it will be very easy. Based on your JS, I would assume the value attribute is empty, but present, which can be targeted with CSS.

```
input[value=""] {display:none;}
```

Or

```
input[type="submit][value=""] {display:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that your function has one extra `}` and it should be `if` not `If`. Then at least the if condition will work.

You can use following CSS to hide the button

```
input[type="submit][value=""] {display:none;}
```

Changed JS code -

```
function goToProdSpec(){
    var ButtonValue = document.getElementById('ProdNo').value;

    if(ButtonValue != ""){
    url = 'http://svr:7018/Enquiries/CMENPROC.rpgle?ProductCode=' + ButtonValue;    
    window.location.href = url;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check empty string with `if(!ButtonValue)`:

```
function goToProdSpec(){
    var ButtonValue = document.getElementById('ProdNo').value;

    If(!ButtonValue){
    url = 'http://svr:7018/Enquiries/CMENPROC.rpgle?ProductCode=' + ButtonValue;    
    window.location.href = url;
    }
}
```